# Часовые пояса в Android

Tags: java, android, дата

Ситуация: в моем приложении два фрагмента. В первом фрагменте пользователь выбирает дату, которая записывается в переменную типа Date. Далее, пользователь меняет в настройках телефона часовой пояс, нажимает на кнопку. Записанная дата передается во второй фрагмент и выводится там в TextView.

Проблема:
Даты на первом и втором фрагментах не совпадают. То есть если стоял у пользователя часовой пояс -11 при выборе даты и +13 при просмотре второго фрагмента, а на первом фрагменте он выбрал 1 июня, то на втором фрагменте он увидит 2 июня.

Как сделать так, чтобы дата не менялась? Из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: почитайте как хранятся данные в Date, о том что такое дата в UTC, и храните дату в UTC.

Comment: @andreich, так вроде Date и хранит время в UTC, разве нет?

Comment: В Date нет инфы о часовом поясе, есть только в Calendar. Выводится в том часовом поясе, в котором укажешь. Обычно не указывают - т.е. в локальном. @BArtWell как вы выводите это время? И в каком формате передаете во второй фрагмент?

Comment: Проблема в вашем коде. Инфа 100%. Кода тут нет. Больше сказать не могу.

Answer (score 2):

Разные часовые пояса, очевидно. Выбрана дана в одном поясе, а просматривается в другом. В Москве сейчас 3 часа ночи, в Петропавловске-Камчатском - 12, полдень, и это один и тот же момент времени.

Используя тип Date, вы сохраняете момент времени.
Если вам нужен ввод только даты то, скорее всего, вам нужно настенное время (wall clock time). Это 21.05.2015 на календаре и 3:00 на часах. В разных часовых поясах это разные моменты времени.

Варианты:

- Хранить и передавать не Date, а в своем классе Год-месяц-день-час-минута-секунда. Либо строкой в формате, который можно потом распарсить (например, вариант ISO8601  `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`). То есть без сохранения информации о часовом поясе. Строка будет парсится каждый раз и получится, что будет парсится как настенное время в текущем часовом поясе.
- Хранить время в GregorianCalendar. Тогда вместе со временем сохранится и часовой пояс, в котором это время было выбрано. Затем выводить время не в текущем часовом поясе, а в исходном (*setTimeZone()* у *SimpleDateFormat*).
- При сохранении и выводе выводе времени указывать один и тот же часовой пояс, например, `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")`. Отображаться будет всегда одинаково, но могут вознить проблемы соответствия реальному времени.
- При изменении часового пояса система рассылает бродкаст [Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED). Можно его ловить и корректировать время.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можете уточнить как можно скорректировать время при получении бродкаста? Для меня самым удобным вариантом было бы просто получить правильный объект Date на выходе.